# How does the adiabatic coefficient $γ$ vary with temperature (200K-20000K)?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, aerodynamics, adiabatic

At high temperatures, such as those encountered in hypersonic flight, γ varies a lot. My problem is that I can‘t find a graph accompanied by an explanation as to how & why it changes under different assumptions (Thermally perfect, calorically perfect, thermochemical equilibrium, Thermochemical non-equilibrium).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This would be different for each gas species. I don't think there is a genetic answer. Also, your temp range goes way above the ionization temperature of most common gases, so you are no longer dealing with a simple neutral gas. Plasma physics is required

Answer (score 1):

One place to start is the NASA Technical Reports Server (ntrs. nasa. gov - take out the spaces) and get *Thermodynamic and Transport Properties of Air and the Combustion Products of Natural Gas and ASTM-A-1 Fuel with Air*, by David Poferl and others, NASA TN D-5452 *. they give the ratio of specific heats $\gamma$ at 3 and 10 atmosphere pressure from 300 to 2500K. The table is at 100K increments.

*I have better luck looking with words in title than document number.

While you are at NTRS get NACA Report 1135 for more tables and information on compressible flow than you may want (*Equations, Tables and Charts for Compressible Flow*). Page 15 has equations for $c_p$ and $\gamma$.

[image: Ratio of specific heats to 2500K]

Answer (score 0):

The adiabatic coefficient is the ration of heat capacities at constant pressure and constant volume $\gamma = \frac{C_p }{ C_V} \overset{ideal gas}{\approx}=\frac{C_V + R }{ C_V}$.

For the model air case, based mostly on diatomic molecules $\require{mhchem} \ce{N2}$ and $\ce{O2}$

From classical thermodynamics:

$$C_V = (3R)_\mathrm{trans} + (2R)_{rot} + (2R)_\mathrm{vibr}$$

where the gas constant $R \approx 8.314 \mathrm{\ J/K/mol} $

Following the classical model of an ideal gas, the molar heat capacity would be temperature independent ( perfect gas ). But due quantum effects and quantization of rotation and vibration energy, this is not true.

For very low temperatures, the molar heat capacities of diatomic molecules are like $$C_V = (3R)_\mathrm{trans}$$ with just a fraction of rotation energy and virtualy zero vibration energy (but zero point vibration), due quantum discrimination.

At room temperature, rotational energy ( but for hydrogen ) is saturated $$C_V = (3R)_\mathrm{trans} + (2R)_{rot}$$

For elevated temperatures, vibrational energy modes with large quantization steps start to kick in and the molar heat capacity converges to

$$C_V = (3R)_\mathrm{trans} + (2R)_{rot} + (2R)_\mathrm{vibr}$$

That all above leads to the adiabatic coeficient decreases in 2 waves with temperature.

For high temperatures like $T \gt 2000 \mathrm{K}$, things get complicated by molecule dissociation and molecule/atom ionization.